# Data truncated, can't import text file to mysql

Tags: mysql

This is the file im trying to import:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     jobdate       |      fulltime      |     dateclose      |      yearexp       |      payrate       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/13/2015         |               True |          1/26/2015 |                  5 |             $30.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/13/2014         |               True |         12/17/2014 |                  7 |             $30.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/27/2014         |               True |         12/27/2014 |                 15 |        $100,000.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/25/2014         |               True |          10/1/2015 |                  5 |         $80,000.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/16/2014         |               True |          1/25/2015 |                  5 |             $18.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/16/2014         |               True |          1/25/2015 |                  8 |             $25.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 11/16/2014         |               True |          2/15/2015 |                  4 |             $19.00 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I keep getting the error Data truncated for column jobyear at row 1 1261

row 1 - 13 doesn't contain data for columns

This is the command im using

```
Load Data Local infile 'C:/Users/Gary/Desktop/XML/job.txt' INTO Table jobs FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

Comment: you're telling mysql that your file is tab-separated. Your file does NOT conform to that. it's not tab-separated. it's space and `|` separated, and the `----` lines are going to be cause problems too.

Comment: Check your column length to store data.

Comment: Ok so I used the tab delim in the access option now i just get some rows dont contain data for columns